# Why colspan doesnt work

Tags: html, html-table, thymeleaf

I have a problem with my code specialy with the colspan part. Here is my code:

```
    <table>
          <tr>
             <th>Phasen Name</th>
             <th>Planned Value</th>
             <th>Actual Cost</th>
             <th>Earned Value</th>
          </tr>
        <th:block th:each="eintrag : ${evaPhasen}">
          <tr>
             <td class="accordion" th:text="${eintrag.key}"></td>
             <td th:text="${eintrag.value.getPlannedValue()}"></td>
             <td th:text="${eintrag.value.getActualCost()}"></td>
             <td th:text="${eintrag.value.getEarnedValue()}"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="display:none">
            <td colspan="4">
              <table>               
                <tr>
                    <th>Workpackage Name</th>
                    <th>Planned Value</th>
                    <th>Actual Cost</th>
                    <th>Earned Value</th>
                </tr>
                <tr th:each="wpDetail : ${evaWP}">
                    <td class="accordion" th:text="${wpDetail.key}"></td> 
                    <td th:text="${wpDetail.value.getPlannedValue()}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${wpDetail.value.getActualCost()}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${wpDetail.value.getEarnedValue()}"></td>  
                </tr>   
            </table>
           </td>                
          </tr> 
         </th:block>
      </table>
```

So my question is when I open the accordion class, the content (table) is showed in the first column of the other table and why not over all 4 columns? I think I'm doing something wrong with the . Here is a picture of the result [colspan]: http://thumbs.picr.de/32846430ew.jpg

Comment: Perhaps, if we saw the resulting html, it might be easier to say?

Comment: The description is not clear enough, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you post a live example on jsFiddle? You can use static content for the table cells. Also I assume there is javascript that you did not include that controls the accordion you mention which could affect it.

Comment: shouldn't "<th:block th:each="eintrag : ${evaPhasen}">...</th:block>" be inside a "<tr>...</tr>" ?

Comment: I uploaded a picture but its very small. Yes there is a javascript running and this works well! The problem is that the loaded table just shows in the first column of the table and not over all 4 columns

Comment: Why, when people ask for the html, do you upload a thumbnail?

Comment: Here is a a picture of the html output [link](https://ibb.co/m0XDnd)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with thymeleaf, but I'm assuming it doesn't alter the table code you have here, it just styles it, or injects content.

So you have a `table`. It starts with a row with 4 `th` elements. Then you have a th element outside a row, which contains a row with 4 `td` elements. I believe maybe you meant to use a `thead`. But then you wouldn't need the `tr` elements within it. If I'm not mistaken, you're incorrectly nesting row-type elements and cell-type elements.

Also, the `td` element with the accordion class is empty. That might be

I can't offer much more without knowing thymeleaf, but your table output maybe should look something like this (it at least achieves the colspan working as intended):

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Phasen Name</th>
        <th>Planned Value</th>
        <th>Actual Cost</th>
        <th>Earned Value</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="accordion" th:text="${eintrag.key}"></td>
        <td th:text="${eintrag.value.getPlannedValue()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${eintrag.value.getActualCost()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${eintrag.value.getEarnedValue()}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Workpackage Name</th>
              <th>Planned Value</th>
              <th>Actual Cost</th>
              <th>Earned Value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="wpDetail : ${evaWP}">
              <td class="accordion" th:text="${wpDetail.key}"></td>
              <td th:text="${wpDetail.value.getPlannedValue()}"></td>
              <td th:text="${wpDetail.value.getActualCost()}"></td>
              <td th:text="${wpDetail.value.getEarnedValue()}"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

That being said, that `th` I removed looks like it could be an each. If it is an iterator, then you may need to have it iterate in a different spot. If you can paste the actual HTML output of your code after the thymeleaf templating is applied, it would much easier for a wider audience to help you.